# Example problems not in P nor in NP-complete but in NP

Tags: computer-science, theory, complexity-theory, computation-theory

I have a course called Algorithm Analysis at college, where we're currently studying the different complexity classes -- P, NP, NP-hard etc.

We've already discussed NP-complete problems as the intersection between NP and NP-hard, and P problems, contained in NP. We've also talked about some examples, mainly of NP-complete problems (k-coloring, k-clique, SAT).

Most of the time, we prove a problem is NP-complete by:

a. Finding a nondeterministic algorithm to solve it (that uses choice, success, fail);

b. Reducing a known NP-complete problem to it.

The thing is that these problems, when run on a deterministic machine (sequentially, instead of simultaneously branching when encountering a choice) have exponential-time solutions.

My question is this -- I've never encountered problems that were solvable neither in polynomial time neither in exponential time; polynomial time problems are in P and exponential-time problems are usually in NP-complete.

There's a helpful Venn diagram here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np_complete

1. I'd like to know **an example of a problem that is neither in P, neither in NP-complete, but in NP**.
2. Also, are intrinsically exponential problems, like **generating the power set of a set NP-complete?** Or does that name only apply for problems for which an exponential time algorithm is used only because there's no other obvious method for solving it?

Ok, so I gave the answer to *Rosh Oxymoron* because he actually listed some examples of problems suspected to be between P and NPC. Thanks for your help guys, and I actually noticed that I put this question in the wrong place.
There's also:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

where I found the following very useful answers to my question:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc
which is specifically about what I asked, and:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52/hierarchies-in-np-under-the-assumption-that-p-np
which is generally interesting, if not exactly related to the initial question.

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Comment: See [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/25967/98) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9063/98) question on [cs.SE].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. BQP problems such as integer factorization and discrete logarithm (cracking RSA and DSA) are thought to be outside of P and are also suspected to be in NP but not in NP-complete. Integer factorization is known to be in NP, and is supposed to be outside of P and NP-complete.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

2. NP is a subset of EXPTIME, but it is expected that NP != EXPTIME (that is, EXPTIME-complete problems are not in NP). Like with P = NP, this is not yet proven (but it is known that P != EXPTIME). For example checking if an algorithm would half after k steps is EXPTIME-complete. Finding the power set is too (obviously).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME

Comment: It's important to stress that 1. is *conjecture*. If P=NP no such problems exist, but if P!=NP we *know* that NPI is not empty.

Answer (score 14):

> I'd like to know an example of a problem that is neither in P, neither in NP-complete, but in NP.

Me too; if you find one go ahead and visit this web page to claim your $1M prize:  https://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem

Comment: @iamrohitbanga To use BQP as P≠NP proof all of these things must be proven: 1. BQP ⊆ NP 2. P ⊊ BQP 3. BQP ∩ NPC = ∅. All of those are currently not known.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no problem known to be in `NP \ NPC`.
2. A problem is in NP if and only if a non-deterministic turing machine can solve it in polynomial time (or, equivalently, a deterministic turing machine can decide it in polynomial time). This is not the case for your example.

   Further it should be pointed out that we do not know whether `P = NP`, so it's perfectly possible (if highly unlikely) that all problems in `NP` can be solved in polynomial time. So if we know that a problem can not be solved in polynomial time, that problem is either not in NP or, if we can prove that it is indeed in NP, we just showed that `NP != P`.

Comment: 1. I thought it was suspected that P≠NP actually?

2. Ah yes, I see your point, a non-deterministic machine would still not be able to find the answer to that problem. So, where is it really, in which class?

Comment: @Dan: 1. Yes, it is believed that `P != NP`, which is why I said that `P = NP` is believed to be false. However since we don't *know* that it is false, we also don't know any problems in `NP \ NPC` (though we might suspect that they exist). 2. It's in `EXPTIME`.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood at first - I didn't pay attention to the _whole sentence_ between the brackets.

Comment: @sepp2k About 1: Usually even if P=NP not all NP problems are considered NP-Complete since you wouldn't really be reducing to them always. Take for example ∅ to which no language with yes-instances can be reduced, but it is in P (algorithm: "return FALSE").

Comment: "(or, equivalently, a deterministic turing machine can decide it in polynomial time)" - This is not equivalent. Whether a DTM exists that can verify a solution is though.

Answer (score 1):

[Qiaochu Yuan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/290), [What techniques exist to show that a problem is not NP-complete?,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9221/what-techniques-exist-to-show-that-a-problem-is-not-np-complete)

might help.